# ошибка PageFragment

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Здравствуйте! Есть:

MyFragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

static final int PAGE_COUNT = 7;

public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
}
```

PageFragment:

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";
public static final String PAGE_TEXT = "page text";

ArrayList<Predmet> itemList = new ArrayList<Predmet>();
MyAdapter boxAdapter;
Button btnAdd, btnRead;
DBHelper dbHelper;
ListView myListView;
Context ctx;

int pageNumber;
int backColor;

public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
    pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
    return pageFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    myListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    // создаем адаптер
    fillData();
    boxAdapter = new MyAdapter(ctx, itemList);
    // настраиваем список
    myListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    myListView.setAdapter(boxAdapter);

    return view;
}

//генерируем данные для адаптера
void fillData() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        itemList.add(new Predmet(Integer.toString(i+1),"",""));
    };
}
```

Подчеркивает "return PageFragment.newInstance(position);" и пишет ошибку:
error: incompatible types
required: Fragment
found:    PageFragment
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в причине ошибки, буду очень признателен.

Comment: Проверьте что во всех случаях используется один и тот же класс фрагмента. Имеется в виду из какой библиотеки он импортирован.\

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте импорты. 
Если стоит

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

то замените это на

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!))) Но теперь появился еще 1 вопрос.

Comment: какой вопрос...?

Comment: Появилась ошибка "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference" и показаны строки на " boxAdapter = new MyAdapter(ctx, itemList);" и "lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);" в адапторе кастомного ListView,  как понимаю, что передаю ctx со значением null, но как исправить это к сожалению не понимаю

Comment: Спасибо,вродь нашел решение!)))

Comment: Покажите значание переманной ctx.